# How to strip off the line information from a Location?

Tags: rascal

Assume I have a location:

```
loc originalLocation = |project://proj/src/Test.java|(15,536,<3,0>,<41,1>),5,11,39)
```

How do I strip off the line info, so I get:

```
 |project://proj/src/Test.java|
```

I tried:

```
 loc l= ||+originalLocation.uri;
```

and:

```
loc l = |originalLocation.uri|
```

but in the last case it is off course handled as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it using the top field in locations.

```
rascal> originalLocation.top
loc: |project://proj/src/Test.java|
```

Comment: (we should update the [tutor page for Source Locations](http://tutor.rascal-mpl.org/Rascal/Expressions/Values/Location/Location.html) on this and perhaps other fields)

Comment: Thanks but indeed this is not (well) explained in the doc